# Running C/C++ binary executable as a docker container

Tags: docker, executable

I am new to container world and exploring options to run my application on a container.Here are the things that I am seeing:

1. When I include compiling and building the C/C++ binary as part of docker image itself, it works fine with out any problems. Container starts and everything works fine.
2. If I try to run an already compiled and existing binary using CMD ["./helloworld"] in a container It throws me this error
   standard_init_linux.go:185: exec user process caused “exec format error”.

Any ideas of how to get out of this problem? This seems like a basic problem that would have been solved already

Here is my dockerfile:

FROM ubuntu

```
COPY . /Users/test//Documents/CPP-Projects/HelloWorld-Static

WORKDIR /Users/test/Documents/CPP-Projects/HelloWorld-Static

CMD ["./build/exe/hellostatic/hellostatic"]
```

Hers is my exe:

```
gobjdump -a build/exe/hellostatic/hellostatic

build/exe/hellostatic/hellostatic: file format mach-o-x86-64

build/exe/hellostatic/hellostatic
```

Here is the error:

```
docker run test

standard_init_linux.go:185: exec user process caused “exec format error”
```

Comment: Don't you read documentation, before asking a question?

Comment: What does this have to do with C or C++ languages?  Binary executables can be generated from a plethora of languages, such as FORTRAN and BASIC.

Comment: With all due respect, do you have any idea what you are doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to run an incompatible binary format in your container...

You are running an Ubuntu-based container (FROM ubuntu) line, but you are trying to run a Mach-O binary. By default, Linux will not run mach-o binaries.

Build your binary for the target platform (Ubuntu/Linux) and it will work well. It appears that you are running Mac OS X, so you could install an Ubuntu VM to compile your binary and transfer it to be used by the container.

When you build it inside the container, it works because it will be built to the right platform.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I was thinking MAC binaries can be run on docker containers. I solved the issue by building the binary for Ubuntu.